# Scheduling Python code to stop and run daily at particular times

Tags: python

I have a python code, using Dash, which reads a CSV file and builds up a dashboard. Now I want the code to get stopped daily at 9:15 AM and restart at 9:30 AM (so that in these 15 minutes, the CSV file gets updated).
How to achieve the same ?

The code runs on one base system, the other users then access the dashboard using link. The code continues to run on the same base system. And SAS is ued to store the file in that base system. So that is why I want that the code stops at a particular time. The file gets refreshed in that system and then the code restarts.

Comment: how is the code running?

Comment: The code runs on one base system, the other users then access the dashboard using link. The code continues to run on the same base system. And SAS is ued to store the file in that base system. So that is why I wish to automate this process. That is the code stopping at a particular time. The file getting refreshed and then the code restarting.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the system it's running on, there's different solutions to your problem.

If you've system access and are on a Linux-based OS, the most straightforward way would be to use `cron`, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron. If you Google you'll find tons of documentation and "how to" guides.

Comment: I am on Windows. I came across schedule package by using which I am able to start the code at a fixed time. But I think I am not able to understand how to stop it.

Comment: If it's not stopping it's probably some infinite loop in your Python program. Or does it exit after successful CSV read when you run it from the console?

Comment: `import schedule
import time

def job():
    dashboard_code

schedule.every().day.at("9:15").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
`

This is the code format. So the code is able to start at the designated time. Please tell me what to add to be able to stop it at a given time.

Comment: Looks like you're just looking for smth brute-force.. would suggest in your while-loop to just check if the time is 09:30 and then kill it by doing `sys.exit(0)`

Comment: Niklas can you please tell me the command for that ? and if we are doing sys.exit(0), will the code run again at 9:15 ?